Android Eproxy - re trigger the VisibilityStates for CarouselModel_ is not functioning when the page resumes
When the fragment resumes, I want to re-trigger the onVisibilityStateChanged using CarouselModel_ in EpoxyRecyclerView.
override fun onResume() {
   epoxyVisibilityTracker.clearVisibilityStates()
    epoxyVisibilityTracker.requestVisibilityCheck()
    super.onResume()
}

This clearVisibilityStates and requestVisibilityCheck are helping to re triggering the onVisibilityStateChanged event for all components except the items inside CarouselModel_
I want to re trigger onVisibilityStateChanged event for CustomEproxyModel_
       val customModels = ArrayList<EpoxyModel<*>>()
        customModels.add(
            CustomEproxyModel_()
                .id(viewId)
                .onVisibilityStateChanged { _, _, visibilityState ->
                    if(visibilityState == VisibilityState.VISIBLE) {
                        Log.d("Eproxy", "CustomEproxyModel_ visible")
                    }
                }
        )
        CarouselModel_()
            .id(viewId)
            .spanSizeOverride { totalSpanCount, _, _ ->
                totalSpanCount
            }.models(customModels)

detach and attach visibilityTracker is not working for me.
 override fun onPause() {
// Detach the visibility tracker from the RecyclerView
        visibilityTracker.detach(epoxyRecyclerView)
}

  override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        
        // Attach the visibility tracker to the RecyclerView
        visibilityTracker.attach(epoxyRecyclerView)
}

